# How to solve Hibernate OGM startup error for MongoDB configured via hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

Trying to connect to a MongoDB instance, I'm getting this error:

[image]
Here's my current approach to configure the environment via hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">MONGODB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database">TEST</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host">127.0.0.1:50196</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port">27017</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.username" >usr</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.password" >pwd</property>
  </session-factory>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect us to do? Black magic? Please provide a [mcve] and/or more additional information

Answer (score 4):

You need to to configure which datastore provider you want to use with what specific configuration options. For example, this is done via the `hibernate.ogm.datastore.database` property that you don't list in your configuration, but *hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database*, which is wrong.

As described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.0/reference/en-US/html/ch11.html#mongodb_specific_configuration_properties), you must provide several of these `hibernate.ogm.datastore.*` properties via configuration when connecting to a mongodb.

So your hibernate.cfg.xml needs to written as:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">MONGODB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database">TEST</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host">127.0.0.1:50196</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port">27017</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username">usr</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password">pwd</property>
</session-factory>
```

Hope, it helps.